# Проблема с использованием метода getMap в GoogleMap

Tags: java, android

Скажите,а что метод getMap "убрали" из гуглкарт?
импорты:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
 private void createMapView(){

    try {
        if( null == googleMap ){

            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id. mapView )).getMap;

            if( null == googleMap ) {
                Toast. makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error creating map",Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException exception){
        Log.e( "mapApp" , exception.toString());
    }

}
```

gRADLE:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pokemongo.pokemon"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вынести этот фрагмент кода в `onCreate` и судя по документации переписать это так:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Ну и под конец `getMap` в Вашем случае не является вызовом метода, а свойства, которого там нет. Значит Ваш код нужно записать так:

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id. mapView )).getMap();
```

Но за его работоспособность я не ручаюсь!

Comment: изменил,но ничег оен поменялось,
.getMap(); по прежнему красный,т.е такого нет метода,а если заменить getmap на getMapAsync(this); тотак же ошибки

Comment: getMapAsync у SupportMapFragment или MapFragment?